# How to pass a base graphics plot as an argument returned from a function without printing in R

Tags: r

If I am plotting something in base graphics

```
doMix <- function() {
    library('mixtools')

    kr=c(sample(100,10000,T), sample(100:200,10000,T))
    kr.mix <- normalmixEM(kr,k=2,maxit=1000000,ECM=T)

    plot.mixEM(kr.mix,density=T, which=2)
}
```

I want to return this plot and add it to a lattice plot that I am calling from another function:

```
## some other stuff
p2 <- xyplot(rnorm(100)~rnorm(100))`
## some other stuff
```

so that I can organize the layout. How can I do this? Obviously, if I could  just do `p1 <- plot.mixEM(kr.mix,density=T, which=2)`, I would but this doesn't work.

Comment: grDevices has recordPlot() and replayPlot(), maybe they can hepl

Answer (score 0):

`plot` does not return anything, unlike `lattice` functions, so you cannot do this.  You will either need to set `par(new=TRUE)` to allow overwriting the existing plot window, or switch to using either `lattice:xyplot` or the `ggplot` package.